# Mask ndarray with boolean ndarray to replace nans

Tags: python, numpy, nan, masked-array

I'm trying to use a boolean mask to address rows in a numpy array:

```
isnan = np.isnan(self.X[:, AGE_COLUMN].astype(float))
self.X[isnan, AGE_COLUMN] = np.mean(self.X[:, AGE_COLUMN].astype(float))
```

isnan and X are `dtype`.

First I check which rows in the age column are nan. And then I want to set these values to the mean of all ages. The debugger has following result for `self.X[isnan, AGE_COLUMN]`:

```
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ....]
```

If I try `self.X[[True, False, True], AGE_COLUMN]` for example it returns the indexed rows. But with the `isnan` array it does not work.

How can I fix this to set the nans to the mean.

Comment: Numpy has `nanmean` and `nan_to_num` functions; those should help.

Comment: the `mean` of `something` and `nan` is `nan`, you should get rid of `nan`s before computing the mean

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows using `numpy.nanmean`: it will **ignore** `NaN`s

```
self.X[isnan, AGE_COLUMN] = np.nanmean(self.X[:, AGE_COLUMN].astype(float))
```

[From the documentation](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

> *numpy.nanmean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=)*
>
> Compute the arithmetic mean along the specified axis,
>   ignoring NaNs.
>
> Returns the average of the array elements. The average is taken over
>   the flattened array by default, otherwise over the specified axis.
>   float64 intermediate and return values are used for integer inputs.
>
> For all-NaN slices, NaN is returned and a RuntimeWarning is raised.